# In C, why can't %o print negative values?

Tags: c, printf, octal

So when I run this:

```
printf("%o", -1);
```

It prints out `37777777777`.

Why do I get this output?

I thought it was first complement of `-1`, but why `3` at the beginning?

Comment: An octal digit represents 3 bits; the number of bits in an integer isn’t typically divisible by 3, and it isn’t here.

Comment: `%o` only prints unsigned integers.

Comment: Because it's a 32 bit number and 37777777777 in octal is 32 bits.

Comment: Additionally, to answer the question in the title, `%o` prints unsigned integers, just like `%x` where you'd get `ffffffff`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the ISO C standard (`C11 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function /8`), `%o` prints out an *unsigned* value in octal:

> **o,u,x,X** - The `unsigned int` argument is converted to unsigned octal (`o`), unsigned decimal (`u`), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (`x` or `X`) ...

Based on your output, you have a 32-bit two's complement `int` type where `-1` is represented as the binary:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
\/\_/\_/ \_/\_/\__/\_/\_/\__/\_/\_/
 3 7  7   7  7   7  7  7   7  7  7
```

with the bottom line showing the octal representation (what you're seeing).

And the *reason* why you're seeing a `3` at the front is because each octal digit represents three bits and 32 is not evenly divisible by three.

However, you should keep in mind that *any* behaviour is acceptable here. As per the ISO quote above, `%o` requires an `unsigned int` and, as per the later sub-section `/9`:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

---

If your `int` was 64-bit, it would be subtly different (as well as longer, obviously). A 32-bit value will have two extra bits at the front (`32 % 3 == 2`) but a 64-bit value has only one (`64 % 3 == 1`). So you would end up with:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
|\_/\_/\__/\_/\_/ \_/\_/\__/\_/\_/\__/\_/\_/ \_/\_/\__/\_/\_/\__/\_/\_/
1 7  7   7  7  7   7  7   7  7  7   7  7  7   7  7   7  7  7   7  7  7
```

Comment: So, if I was to run this on a 64-bit system, the output would be different?

Comment: @NerminaAvdić, yes, because the data type is wider. And, because `64 % 3` is 1, the first digit would be a single binary `1` rather than the two-bit binary `11`, hence `177777..7777`. I'll update the answer to show that as well.

Comment: In fact the behavior is undefined. The `%o` format specifier *requires* an argument of type `unsigned int`. There's a special rule that lets you use corresponding signed and unsigned types as arguments *when the value is representable in both*, but it doesn't apply here. `-1` is of type `int`. Treating it as if it were of type `unsigned int`, with the same representation, is the most likely actual behavior, but it's not guaranteed. If you really want to do that, use a cast (explicit conversion): `printf("%o", (unsigned int)-1)`.

Comment: Good point, @Keith, added that to the answer (with the relevant pointer to the standard).

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to print a negative number in octal or even hex!! Fortunately, the need to do so is pretty rare. You can of course test whether the number is negative and print a minus sign before it:

```
 if (i < 0)
    printf("-%o",-i);
 else 
    printf("%o",i);
```

Answer (score -1):

While it typically doesn't make much sense to display a signed number in any base other than decimal, there's nothing special about decimal that says it's the only base that can display negatives.

For example, if you have two addresses, you may want to know the difference between them, which could be negative. And of course you would want to see that result as hex.

In fact, Python is completely fine with natively displaying negative hex values.

So, here's a way to display negative numbers using a specifier other than `%d`, namely `%o`:

```
int x = -1;
printf("%s%o", x<0 ? "-" : "", x<0 ? 0u-x : 0u+x);
```

Comment: Just because *you* don't think it makes sense to display negative numbers in any base but 10, doesn't mean my answer should be downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote but this answer passes an `int` argument to `printf("…%o`,  whereas it would be nice to avoid it.

Comment: I also didn't downvote but I *have* been caught out before blindly negating integers - it doesn't always do what you generally expect, particularly with `INT_MIN` :-)

Comment: Perhaps change to `x<0 ? 0u-x : 0u+x`?

Comment: Thanks @chux, I like that