# why does it print fffffff5 instead of -b

Tags: c, input, output

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%x",-11);
    return 0;
}
```

output
fffffff5

I also tried using o as a format specifier, it prints something else

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%o",-11);
    return 0;
}
```

output
37777777765

Comment: %x prints out the unsigned bitwise representation of a number. Negative numbers are in twos complement form so -1 = 0xffffffff, -2 = 0xfffffffe etc. %X does the same but in capitals. Sometimes the latter is easier to read - proportional fonts on long numbers can be a bit distracting. If you add b to the printed value you get zero (and a carry).

Comment: I think using `%x` with signed number is technically undefined behavior although in reality it seldom matters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In C, why can't %o print negative values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42380887/in-c-why-cant-o-print-negative-values)

Comment: ... yes, the argument corresponding to a `%x` or `%o` conversion specifier is required to be an `unsigned int`, and the spec says "If any argument is not the
correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: %o is for octal ie base 8 formatting.